# regular expression to extract all the attributes of a div

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a requirement to extract the all the attributes of some tag. so i want to go for regex for this.for example `<sometag attr1="val1" attr2="val2" ></sometag>`. i want the attributes and values as name value pairs.

Any help appreciated

thanks

Comment: I don't think you can do that with a regular expression.  Not directly, anyways.

Comment: why don't you want to use `attributes` property of an `Element`?

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you failed? You want us to code a solution for you?

Answer (score 5):

```
var s = '<sometag attr1="val1" attr2="val2" ></sometag>';
var reg = /\s(\w+?)="(.+?)"/g;
while( true ) {
    var res = reg.exec( s );
    if( res !== null ) {
        alert( 'name = '+res[1] );
        alert( 'value = '+res[2] );
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about attributes that aren't in double quotes (e.g. either single quotes or no quotes)? Also won't work for other elements for attributes that have no value (e.g. *option@selected*).

Comment: Yes it can be tweaked a lot, It can't handle extra whitespace around = too, I didn't want to write a full-featured html parser for the questioner just a quick example to show how it should be done. anyway to address some of the issues you mentioned and the one I mentioned the regex can be modified like this `/\s(\w+?)(?:\s*)=(?:\s*)["'](.*?)["']/g`

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match_all( '/\s(\w+?)="(.+?)"/', '<sometag attr1="val1" attr2="val2" ></sometag>', $matches );
for( $i = 0; $i < count( $matches[1] ); ++$i ) {
    $name = $matches[1][$i];
    $value = $matches[2][$i];
    echo 'name'.$i.' = "'.$name.'", value'.$i.' = "'.$value.'", ';
}
```

result:

```
name0 = "attr1", value0 = "val1", name1 = "attr2", value1 = "val2",
```

of course you need to tweak this to fit your need and deal with bad html.

Comment: the question tags specify Javascript, not PHP.

Comment: oh sorry rewriting in javascript in a few sec

Comment: autumn thanks for the quick reply . i need it in java script.

Comment: I posted the javascript answer too, I deleted this I don't know why it's still here.

Comment: @autumn can u repost it again.

Comment: repost the javascript answer? it's there I see it as the first answer now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jquery][1] to get all attrubutes of an element

```
$('sometag').getAttributes();
```

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/getAttributes

Answer (score 1):

A regex is not required. Much easier, use [Element.attributes()](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/elementproperties.shtml):

```
var attributes = element.attributes();
```

"Returns an array (NamedNodeMap) containing all the attributes defined for the element in question, including custom attributes." See the link for examples on how to access each attribute and it's value.

Comment: Except it won't work for any non-standard attributes that have been defined on the element.

Comment: @aroth: well according to the link it _will_ work for custom attributes, although I haven't confirmed.

Comment: I tried it in my fiddle and it didn't seem to work for custom attributes, at least not on dynamically created elements (edit:  it works if the custom attribs are added in the markup, but not if they are added dynamically at runtime, it seems):  http://jsfiddle.net/cgj5G/1/

Comment: my problem is i am getting as not a element some text content. i want all the attributes as arry

Comment: `attributes` is a _property_ of an element (an array), not a _method_.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in native JavaScript by using a regular expression.  Using native JavaScript you have a couple of basic options.  You can enumerate all of the node's properties and intelligently filter to get just the things you want, like:

```
window.extractAttributes = function(node) {
    var attribString = "";
    var template = document.createElement(node.tagName);
    template.innerHTML = node.innerHTML;
    for (var key in node) {
        if (typeof node[key] == "string" && node[key] != "" && ! template[key]) {
            if (attribString.length > 0) {
                attribString += ", ";
            }
            attribString += key + "=" + node[key];
        }
    }

    return attribString;
};
```

Or you can use `Element.attributes` to iterate the list of declared attributes (note that this may not detect non-standard attribute values that are added dynamically at runtime), like:

```
window.extractAttributesAlternate = function(node) {
    var attribString = "";
    for (var index = 0; index < node.attributes.length; index++) {
        if (attribString.length > 0) {
            attribString += ", ";
        }
        attribString += node.attributes[index].name+ "=" + node.attributes[index].nodeValue;
    }

    return attribString;
};
```

Note that the first approach may not pick up custom attributes that have been defined in the page markup, and that the second approach may not pick up custom attributes that have been defined dynamically by JavaScript on the page.

Which gives us option 3.  You can enumerate the attributes both ways, and then merge the results.  This has the benefit of being able to reliably pick up upon any custom attributes no matter when/how they were added to the element.

Here's an example of all 3 options:  http://jsfiddle.net/cgj5G/3/

Comment: +1 for thorough answer. Might be worth explaining the difference between HTML attributes and DOM properties. What should happen where the attribute has a different value to the related DOM property?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML parser, because provided input is well-formed XML.

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* use Regex for this! Javacript's DOM already has all the information you need, easily accessible.

List all attributes of a DOM element:

```
var element = document.getElementById('myElementName');
var attributes = element.attributes;
for(var attr=0; attr<attributes.length; attr++) {
    alert(attributes[attr].name+" = "+attributes[attr].nodeValue);
}
```

(tested above code in FF5, IE8, Opera11.5, Chrome12: Works in all of them, even with non-standard attributes)

Comment: Does *not* work reliably with non-standard attributes that are added dyanmically (at least in Chrome and Firefox), see:  http://jsfiddle.net/cgj5G/2/

Answer (score 0):

Given the text of a single element which includes its start and end tags (equivalent of the element's `outerHTML`), the following function will return an object containing all of the attribute name=value pairs. Each attribute value can be single quoted, double quoted or un-quoted. Attribute values are optional and if not present will take on the attribute's name.

```js
function getElemAttributes(elemText) {
    // Regex to pick out start tag from start of element's HTML.
    var re_start_tag = /^<\w+\b(?:\s+[\w\-.:]+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[\w\-.:]+))?)*\s*\/?>/;
    var start_tag = elemText.match(re_start_tag);
    start_tag = start_tag ? start_tag[0] : '';
    // Regex to pick out attribute name and (optional) value from start tag.
    var re_attribs = /\s+([\w\-.:]+)(\s*=\s*(?:"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'|([\w\-.:]+)))?/g;
    var attribs = {};   // Store attribute name=value pairs in object.
    var match = re_attribs.exec(start_tag);
    while (match != null) {
        var attrib = match[1];  // Attribute name in $1.
        var value  = match[1];  // Assume no value specified.
        if (match[2]) { // If match[2] is set, then attribute has a value.
            value = match[3] ? match[3] : // Attribute value is in $3, $4 or $5.
                    match[4] ? match[4] : match[5];
        }
        attribs[attrib] = value;
        match = re_attribs.exec(start_tag);
    }
    return attribs;
}
```

Given this input:

`<sometag attr1="val1" attr2='val2' attr3=val3 attr4 >TEST</sometag>`

This is the output:

```js
attrib = {
    attr1: "val1",
    attr2: "val2",
    attr3: "val3",
    attr4: "attr4"
    };
```