# Javascript: Regex to get values from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I suck at regexes so need some help with this, if I pass the below string into someFunction(str)

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" bgcolor="red">
```

how can I get back an array like so:

```
arr[table] = "";
arr[width] = "100%";
arr[border] = "border";
arr[cellspacing] = "cellspacing";
arr[bgcolor] = "cellpadding";
```

or in other words, the first part of the array the tag name and the other parts its properties.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have access to the element in question as a DOM object, use it, instead of taking a string representation of it and trying to parse it.

Comment: I dont, I just have the above string and the reason I am doing this is so that I can convert it into a DOM object...

Comment: [regular expression to extract all the attributes of a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732260/regular-expression-to-extract-all-the-attributes-of-a-div/6732793#6732793)

Comment: @nobody, close, but not getting the tag name...

Comment: you can get the tag name with a separate regex like this: `/<\s*(\w+?)/` (res[1] will contain the tag name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way I would handle it:

```
var str = '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" bgcolor="red">'
var arySplits = str.split(' ');
var aryFinalVals = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < arySplits.length; i++) {
    var arySubSplits = arySplits[i].split('=');
    aryFinalVals[arySubSplits[0].replace(/</, '')] = (arySubSplits[1]) ? arySubSplits[1].replace(/"/g, '').replace(/>/, '') : '';
}
```

**Summary:**

1. Split string using the spaces.
2. Loop through the array of property pairs and split by the `=`.
3. Remove the double quotes and closing tag.

Comment: Makes sense there, but how to get the tag name as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
/([a-z]+)="([a-z0-9%]+)"/g
```

This is quick and dirty, though, not very resilient to variations... more "blindly":

```
/([^=]+)=("[^"]+")/g
```

the latter one will match everything that is not `=` just preceding a `=`, then ignore the `=` and match what is between `"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert a string to a DOM object, you should be able to use innerHTML to invoke the browser's HTML parser:

```
var strToObj = function(str) {
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.innerHTML = str;
    return el.childNodes[0];
}
document.body.appendChild(strToObj('<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" bgcolor="red">'))
```

Comment: Not allowed to use innerHTML :(

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty proof of concept:

```
var input = '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" bgcolor="red">';
var properties = {};
var tempNode = document.createElement("div");
tempNode.innerHTML = input;

for(var p in tempNode.firstChild.attributes){
    if( tempNode.firstChild.attributes.hasOwnProperty(p) ){
        properties[tempNode.firstChild.attributes[p].name] = tempNode.firstChild.attributes[p].value;
    }
}
```

It's not fully tested and it makes lots of assumptions, but I hope it can give you an idea.